# Project without blank spaces will be compiled faster?

Tags: compiler-construction

As far as I know all the compiler and the interpreter will ignore the blank spaces in my projects.
So, if I suppose that I have a project composed by 2 thousand line, there are so much blank spaces.
In this case, my project will be compiled more slowly than a project without them?

Comment: I think so .. because the compiler must have 'Parsing' session ..

Comment: I doubt it takes the computer that much time to ignore whitespace regardless of what this project is written in. Blank lines are for the poor humans that have to read your code and that makes them rather important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance Implications of Using Spaces Instead of Tabs for Indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308018/performance-implications-of-using-spaces-instead-of-tabs-for-indentation)

Comment: @matzone Whitespace has nothing to do with parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ignoring whitespace is possibly the fastest operation there is in a compiler. If it tips the I/O required over into an additional disk read you might notice a tiny difference. It's not worth worrying about, and it certainly isn't worth defacing your source files for. A 2000 line project is nothing to a compiler.

Comment: So,it is better have a readable code rather than earn a few milliseconds to compile it!

Comment: Of course it is. Compilation is essentially free. Reading code, even your own, isn't.